# Magento 2: Getting unknown error on Reviews tab on product details page

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I'm getting this error suddenly on Reviews tab on product details page as:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::setResponse() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract, instance of Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento21\vendor\magento\framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Output\Firebug.php on line 61 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento21\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Abstract.php on line 70' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento21\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento21\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Abstract.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 70, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento21\vendor\magento\framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Output\Firebug.php(61): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract->setResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #2 C:\xampp\htd in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento21\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php on line 61

[image]

I'm not sure what this error means and haven't made any changes in the files mentioned in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was the issue but I had enabled profiler in htaccess file using following line

```
SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER "html"
```

I have removed that line and now the error is gone. Not sure why enabling the profiler was giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear var/cache car/di var/generation

Try to recompile your code generation.

Check also your last di.xml changes.

Thanks,

Comment: I did the above mentioned steps but still no luck, also changes that were made in di.xml were changing following content `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
` because CSS and links were not loading properly in Admin panel